# Jquery Ajax can't post model to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I can retrieve the model from view to my script but posting it to controller is not working.
The model I get from ajax is null. Why ? Is this a some kind of type problem? I can't see why, please help.

My script:

```
$('#addresssendbutton').on('click', function () {
    var valdata = $("#serializer").serialize();
    console.log(valdata); //This shows me all the data without missing
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/SaveClientAddress',
        data: { 'clientAddress': valdata },
        success: function (response) {
            Swal.fire({
                position: 'top-end',
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Adresiniz kaydedildi...',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            })
        },
        error: function (response) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Hata...',
                text: response.errormessage,
            })
        }
    });
});
```

My Controller:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> SaveClientAddress(ClientAddress clientAddress)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(clientAddress.clientaddress_cityname);
        if(!db.ClientAddress.Where(x=>x.client_id == clientAddress.client_id).Any())
        {
            db.ClientAddress.Add(clientAddress);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Json(new
            {
                success= true,
                error=false
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                success=false,
                error=true,
                errormessage = "Sistemde zaten kayıtlı bir adresiniz var."
            });
        }
        
        
    }
```

Edit:
ClientAddress Model:

```
[Table("clientaddress_tbl")]
public class ClientAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int clientaddress_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int? client_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string clientaddress_cityname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string clientaddress_districtname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string clientaddress_neighborhoodname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string clientaddress_streetname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string clientaddress_apartmentnumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string clientaddress_buildingnumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string clientaddress_addressdescription { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client{ get; set; }
}
```

And the console.log(valdata):

clientaddress_cityname=istanbul&clientaddress_districtname=umraniye&clientaddress_neighborhoodname=site&clientaddress_streetname=evren&clientaddress_buildingnumber=54&clientaddress_apartmentnumber=9&clientaddress_addressdescription=xxxxxx&client_id=1

I get client_id from session and don't have any empty fields in model except clientaddress_id.

Comment: It will be `null` if your `data { clientAddress: valdata }` doesn't match *exactly* with your class `ClientAddress` (neither of which you've included).  Get *any* post working first with basic data such as an `id` then a simple class (maybe ClientAddress is simple), but with eg just an ID and a string properties - before complex classes with nested classes

Comment: Please include you ClientAddress model and the response from console.log(valdata);

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm working with Code-First and except the clientaddress_id field from the model I'm passing all the data. Shouldn't it be fine?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Okay just a second.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I've included those.

Comment: Can you post the view too, pls?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out by making this change:

```
$('#addresssendbutton').on('click', function () {
var valdata = $("#serializer").serialize();
console.log(valdata); //This shows me all the data without missing
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/SaveClientAddress',
    data: valdata // Change data to this
    success: function (response) {
        Swal.fire({
            position: 'top-end',
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Adresiniz kaydedildi...',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
        })
    },
    error: function (response) {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Hata...',
            text: response.errormessage,
        })
    }
});
```

});

And in my controller:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> SaveClientAddress(ClientAddress data)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to fix your ajax data.  Assuming that your form id  is "serializer"

```
var valdata = $("#serializer").serialize();
// or I usually use
var valdata = $("#serializer").serializeArray();

......

 data:  valdata ,
.........
```